# How to store user defined class objects in Android App for future use and manipulation?

Tags: java, android, persistence

I have created a class which I will be using objects of in my Android Application. I want to be able to store these objects inside the application so that when the user closes it and starts again, the previous created objects will not be lost. My intentions are to use the stored attributes of the class objects and represent them in a list view. An extract of the class is below:

```
public class Object {
    private ArrayList<String> listOfProducts = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> photos = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    private String date;
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to store the created objects for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for a database mechanism. Android uses SQLite for that purpose, and it fit's your use case perfectly.

You can read more about Androids storage mechanisms here, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), and more about SQLite in an Android application [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).

Comment: Can you still store the lists in the database, I will need to be able to access these lists and the contents for the list view rows?

Comment: You can't store `ArrayLists`, you have to serialise them into rows of your database and store them.

Comment: Will there be any issues with ArrayList<Bitmap> ?

Comment: You have to save the `Bitmap` to disk and store the path to the `Bitmap`.